# how to set a range as default date in keith wood's datepicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, date-range

how to set a "range" by default in keith wood's datepicker ?? [link text](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its been more than a month and no one answered. So putting my own answer down so that anyone with same problem shall find it helpful..

If I wanted to set a date range as default, I'd calculate the 2 dates I wanted, and set it as the value of the datepicker's textbox.

For example, if I had datepicker set to show dates like this : Nov 1,2010 to Dec 1, 2010

Then if I wanted to set default date as Jan 1, 2011 to Feb 1, 2011, I'd simply write this to textbox using jquery, : `$('#textbox').val('Jan 1, 2011 to Feb 1, 2011');`

Datepicker will select those dates in that tool for you..

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#input').datepick({
    yearRange: 'c-100:c-10'
});
```

c-x means x years before now.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer:

> $('#datesField').datepick('setDate', startDae, endDate);